# Embed graphhopper into project

Tags: java, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I would like to embed `graphhopper` into my java application (J2EE) in order to calculate route distances between many points on the map. Points are given by their longitudes and latitudes. I don't need to render the map.

Can you give step by step details how to do that?

[This link](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.4/docs/core/routing.md) describes lines of code to be added. But it doesn't tell how to import graphhopper classes into my project.

I downloaded .pbf for my region and graphhopper project itself and getting stuck how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

> But it doesn't tell how to import graphhopper classes into my project.

Take a look into the [quickstart](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.4/docs/core/quickstart-from-source.md). You need to include the graphhopper dependencies via maven or gradle:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphhopper</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphhopper</artifactId>
  <version>0.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you need the details about the imports for graphhopper just use an IDE to automatically import those (e.g. NetBeans, IntelliJ, Eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you cloned the graphhopper project you can build the jar

`mvn clean install`

which will create a jar in `core/target` with the current snapshot version of graphhopper (or checkout one of the releases to get a specific version). Just add this jar file to your project like you would any other third party jar.

Then to "import" your pbf file into graphhopper speak you would run from the graphhopper project directory...

`./graphhopper.sh import <pbf_file>`

which will create a directory in the same location and name as your pbf file but with "-gh" tacked onto the end of the filename. This is the directory that you will point your code to for graphhopper to read. I'm guessing this should be explained in the link you provided above.

Comment: Thank you! But ./graphhopper.sh import <pbf_file> didn't work giving errors. So I tried ./graphhopper.sh web <pbf_file> instead which created -gh folder with 5 files.

Comment: What errors did you get? import should create a -gh folder with 5 files. Are you sure it wasn't import that created those? What size are the files?

Comment: I forget what exact errors happened, but the size of the files 258Mb for Australia in total. I am sure.

Comment: That honestly doesn't sound like an unreasonable size for the files. But without more info on the error you are getting I can't really do much on that front.